# Sublime Text Sequence

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

As you can see in the screenshot below, I want to change all the `1`'s in the red box into a sequence from `1` to `1000`

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3JYvL.png]

I done some searching and ended up with two plugins for sublime text that make sequences but still can't make use of them in this situation the plugins are "[Incrementor](https://github.com/eBookArchitects/Incrementor)" and "[Text Pastry](https://github.com/duydao/Text-Pastry)"
I installed both using package control but they don't seem to work properly (or maybe I'm doing t wrong)

Comment: You're using the wrong tool for the job. Are you on *nix (or have bash on Windows)? `for i in {1..1000}; do echo "<img src=http://targetname/file?r=$i></img>"; done`

Comment: From the screenshot, you're on Windows so bash may not be immediately available... but you can run the command like I did at http://ideone.com/xcritk

Comment: I can use bash as well
I dual-boot Ubuntu with Windows
Any Linux solution is welcome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may not be the solution you asked for, but you can try this:

Go to this website http://textmechanic.co/Generate-List-of-Numbers.html

**Prefix numbers:** `<img src=http://targetname/file?r=`
**suffix with:** `</img>`

Click **Generate List of Numbers**.

```
<img src=http://targetname/file?r=1</img>
<img src=http://targetname/file?r=2</img>
<img src=http://targetname/file?r=3</img>
<img src=http://targetname/file?r=4</img>
<img src=http://targetname/file?r=5</img>
<img src=http://targetname/file?r=6</img>
<img src=http://targetname/file?r=7</img>
<img src=http://targetname/file?r=8</img>
<img src=http://targetname/file?r=9</img>
<img src=http://targetname/file?r=10</img>
<img src=http://targetname/file?r=11</img>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

It's really easy using the emmet plugin for sublime text: https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Emmet

1) Define HTML syntax in an empty file and paste this line:

```
img[src="http://targetname/file?r=$"]*1000
```

2) Then just place your cursor at the end of the line above and hit `TAB`

Hope this helps!